# Fixed div hides other divs under it

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

How do you keep the div fixed and other div on the next "line" but not under it when the page first loads.
http://codepen.io/alexdj1983/pen/raQrEK

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header"><h1></h1></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the tops of the elements below the header, in your code pen you can do this by adding:

```
top: 150px;
position: relative;
```

to the style of the other elements. I would personally prefer to wrap the two floated divs in another div as a container and set top on that, but it isn't really necessary.

See here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPQqGb